# SPA React-okta sign in widget

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, okta, okta-signin-widget

'I am trying to follow this tutorial I found on Youtube on how to integrate a okta sign in widget to a React SPA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5j4FXMQBzmg&t=358s

but, I think it is a little outdated because it tried to use a ImplicitCallBack when trying to trying to pass in a redirect_uri and when you would try to log into the widget there would be a 400 error saying only login was permitted

I changed it to a LoginCallback, but now when you login to the widget the URL says

error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=The+response+type+is+not+supported+by+the+authorization+server.+Configured+response+types%3A+%5Bcode%5D.

and wont load the inside "staff portal"

I tried using this page to make a config class because maybe it was missing parameters

https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa/react/main/#create-an-okta-app-integration

and this page but i dont know how to integrate the new and old code

https://developer.okta.com/code/react/okta_react_sign-in_widget/#add-an-openid-connect-client-in-okta

this is the code

github.com/bradtraversy/react_otka_auth

only things i changed were on the app. js anywhere it said Implicit to login i also realized this uses okta version 2 or something opposed to the version 3 and 4 there are now

Comment: Are you able to publish your project to GitHub so I can try to configure it and run it with my Okta OIDC app's information? Another thing you might try is installing the Okta CLI (https://cli.okta.com), run `okta login` to configure it with your org, then run `okta start react`. This doesn't use the widget. It uses the (more secure) redirect model instead.

Comment: Yes, right away

Comment: https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_otka_auth      this is the code the only things i changed were on the app. js anywhere it said Implicit to login i also realized this uses okta version 2 or something opposed to the version 3 and 4 there are now

Comment: I upgraded your project to use the latest SDKs and created a PR at https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_otka_auth/pull/2. I hope this helps!